# Multiple similar values simulation

Tags: risk-management, monte-carlo, probability, analysis

Perhaps some of you came across the following task that I am trying to automate for @RISK, VOSE or other simulation software?

I have a question as we are trying to use the software to estimate the project sizing by modelling each step along the way.

Project contains three different types of steps (A,B,C) defined by their own distributions and the number of each might not be equal (N of A's, M B's, K of C's). As per statistics rules I will need to generate a value for each of A's, each of B's and each of C's and then add them up together.

I cannot generate one value and then just multiply it as each event is unique on its own. I want to have the model being locked in a separate tab and not modified, while as the first page should contain the N,M, and K where user should input parameters. How can I allow the number of variables change in accordance to the numbers of N,M, and K?